# TouchableNativeFeedback onLongPress radius not affected

Tags: react-native, ripple, react-native-elements

I use `TouchableNativeFeedback` to show a nice ripple effect on Android, I use a `<View>` wrapper over `TouchableNativeFeedback` to solve a borderRadius problem on it ([See here: **react native elements issue**](https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements/issues/328)).

When I perform a longPress, then the borderRadius fix does not have any affect.

[image: Border radius during long press]